# How to set batch variable with java (System.out.println) result

Tags: java, windows, cmd

Is there a best/shortest way of doing this:

```
java -cp . compare %rel1% %rel2% > out
set /p result=<out
del out
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code is the shortest, but it needs a temporary file, which makes it slow.

The "usual" method to get the output of a command is a `for` loop:

```
for /f %%a in ('java -cp . compare %rel1% %rel2%') do set result=%%a
```

(to use it on command line, use a single percent sign only `%a` instead of `%%a`)

There are a lot of options with the `for` command, which makes it one of the most useful commands in batch. See `for /?` for details.